# Blocking wait on future OUTSIDE of async functions

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await, future

I'm starting to get pretty frustrated with Dart's `async` ...

All I want is lazily load some value and assign it to a property in my class:

```
Future<String> getMeSomeBar() async => "bar";
class Foo {
  late String bar = await getMeSomeBar();
}
```

this doesn't work, of course.

But what really drives me mad is that I know Kotlin has a [`runBlocking`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html) function that is designed for cases exactly like that and there just doesn't seem to be a Dart equivalent or pattern that would allow me to do the same.

At least not one that I've found, so far.

I can't even do a basic spin-lock in Dart because there's no way to check for the state of a `Future`...

So because `getMeSomeBar` is outside of my control, I need to make`Foo.bar` a `Future<String>`.

Which means I have to make whatever function accesses `Foo.bar` an `async` function.

Which means I have to make whatever functions accesses *that* function, an `async` function.

Which means I have to make whatever functions accesses *those* function `async` too.

Which means ...

You get the point. In the end, the whole bloody app is going to be asynchronous simply because I seem to have absolutely no way to block a thread/isolate until a `Future` is completed.

That can't be the solution?!

Is there a way to avoid this?

(No, using `then` doesn't help because then you're either waiting for the completion of *that* `Future` - which again, you seem to only be able to do in an `async` function - or you're gambling on your `Future`s' returning "in time" - which is just plain stupid.)

Comment: Blocking the thread would cause the UI to be unresponsive/freeze until the future is completed, which would not provide a good user experience. And yes a function that depends on an `async` function is `async` itself because it cannot provide an immediate answer.

Comment: very strange, but in this case you can still get angry and go crazy due to the fact that Dart is generally single-threaded, there are no coroutines or their equivalent. outrageous

Comment: Blocking on an asynchronous call is a kludge and generally is unsafe.  Asynchronous functions inherently depend on an event loop; blocking necessarily entails polling the event loop within your synchronous function call and executing event callbacks, which could potentially result in your blocking function (or any of its callers) being unexpectedly re-entrant.  The proper thing to do is to just embrace async and to rely on callbacks.

Comment: Also: "I can't even do a basic spin-lock in Dart because there's no way to check for the state of a `Future`..." No, that's not why.  You could fairly easily wrap `Future` so that you can poll its state (that's what I did with my [`PollableFuture`](https://pub.dev/documentation/dartbag/latest/misc/PollableFuture-class.html) class), but that wouldn't help you create a spin-lock because a spin-lock would prevent the main event loop from running, so `Future`s would never complete.

Comment: If you really don't want to make `Foo.bar` return a `Future<String>`, then you have to settle for it synchronously returning some cached value that potentially could be stale (and sometimes that's okay).  You even could set a flag when an asynchronous operation that could update that value is in-flight, and then you callers would know when the value is stale.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a scalable solution for you, but you could delay building your `Foo` class until the completion of a `Future<T>`, effectively creating an asynchronous factory of `Future<Foo>`.

You could then (1) use that `Future<Foo>` in a `FutureBuilder` widget that listens for `Future<Foo>` to resolve before building your real layout, or (2) you could use your own `Completer<Foo>` in a stateful widget to update the state when done.

Also: if you have to await several Futures to build `Foo`, you can use `Future.all(...)` in your `Foo.fromAsyncCall` Future-factory.

Here's an example:

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      // home: Example1(),
      home: Example2(),
    );
  }
}

// a standin for some object
Future<String> getMeSomeBar() async {
  // just an arbitrary delay
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
  return 'bar';
}

// a standin for some class
class Foo1 {
  final String bar;

  const Foo1(this.bar);

  // You can create a function that will build your object upon the completion
  //  of a future
  static Future<Foo1> fromAsyncCall([dynamic someArgs]) => Future(() async {
        // you can access someArgs in here, if you need to
        String bar = await getMeSomeBar();
        return Foo1(bar);
      });
}

// EX.1 - You could try to use a FutureBuilder listening for the completion of
//  the future
class Example1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example1({super.key});

  @override
  State<Example1> createState() => _Example1State();
}

class _Example1State extends State<Example1> {
  late Future<Foo1> foo1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    foo1 = Foo1.fromAsyncCall();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    foo1.ignore();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: foo1,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Foo1> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(
                  snapshot.data!.bar,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                );
              }
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text(
                  snapshot.error?.toString() ?? 'Error',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                );
              }
              return CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive();
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
}

// EX.2 - You could do it yourself by listening for a Completer. Unfortunately,
//  the future value that the completer wraps is a Future<T> so you can't
//  directly access the future's inner value/error here - you'd have the same
//  problem
class Example2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example2({super.key});

  @override
  State<Example2> createState() => _Example2State();
}

class _Example2State extends State<Example2> {
  final Completer<void> _completer = Completer();
  Foo1? _value;
  Object? _error;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Foo1.fromAsyncCall().then((Foo1 value) {
      if (_completer.isCompleted || !mounted) return;
      setState(() {
        _completer.complete();
        _value = value;
      });
    }).catchError((Object error, StackTrace _) {
      if (_completer.isCompleted || !mounted) return;
      setState(() {
        _completer.completeError(error);
        _error = error;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget? child;
    if (_completer.isCompleted) {
      if (_value != null) {
        child = Text(
          _value!.bar,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
        );
      }
      if (_error != null) {
        child = Text(
          _error.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    child ??= CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive();

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: child,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, you could try to alter your class in such a way where it can complete itself in some form of late-valued fields. I wouldn't recommend that because if you try to access `bar` before it has completed it could throw an error.

```dart
class Foo2 {
  final Completer<void> _completer = Completer();
  List<void Function(String)>? _callbacks;

  bool get isCompleted => _completer.isCompleted;

  late final String bar;

  Foo2({
    required FutureOr<String> bar,
    Iterable<void Function(String)>? onCompletedCallbacks,
  }) {
    _callbacks = onCompletedCallbacks?.toList();
    _completer.future.then((value) {
      if (_callbacks == null) return;
      for (void Function(String) callback in _callbacks!) {
        callback(this.bar);
      }
      _callbacks = null; // forget the callbacks now: we are done
    });
    if (bar is Future<String>) {
      bar.then((value) {
        this.bar = value;
        _completer.complete();
      });
      return;
    }
    this.bar = bar;
    _completer.complete();
  }

  void addListener(void Function(String) callback) {
    if (isCompleted) {
      callback(bar);
      return;
    }
    _callbacks ??= [];
    _callbacks!.add(callback);
  }

  void removeListener(void Function(String) callback) {
    _callbacks?.remove(callback);
  }
}
```